# Replicate angular example from plunker in fiddle using external resources

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to replicate this example from plunker in fiddle with no luck so far after several attempts. 
Here are the two links:http://plnkr.co/edit/fc5vW0?p=preview and http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/pnQFQ/ I am assuming that I don't need to include these two libs in fiddles'  external resources:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I also just cut and pasted the bootstrap css. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared an app in your example. The .module function is referencing `myApp`, but there's no such declaration in your code.

Wrap your code in:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">....</div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnQFQ/2/

Comment: Of course, contained in <script src="app.js"></script> originally. Missing a vote to vote you up but many thanks Mike.